# Pathconvert with relative file names

Tags: ant, mapper

In folder, src, I have a set of subfolders with java source code:

/a/A.java

/a/b/B.java

/a/b/c/C.java

I need a property with the following value:

```
src/a/A.java,src/a/b/B.java,src/a/b/c/C.java
```

I tried the following:

```
<pathconvert property="list-of-files">
  <globmapper from="*" to="src/*"/>
  <fileset dir=${src-folder}/>
</pathconvert>
```

but I end up with the following value on my property:

```
src/full/path/to/folder_a/a/A.java,src/full/path/to/folder_a/a/b/B.java,src/full/path/to/folder_a/a/b/c/C.java
```

How can I accomplish what I want? Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `map` parameter of [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) for this.

First get the full path to your src dir by appending its path to the value of the `basedir` property. Then use that as the `from` attribute of your map.

```
<property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}${file.separator}${src-folder}"/>
<pathconvert property="list-of-files">
  <map from="${src.dir}" to="src"/>
  <fileset dir="${src-folder}"/>
</pathconvert>
```

Comment: You may also obtain the absolute path with location instead of value: `<property name="src.dir" location="${src-folder}" />`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if someone needs to get relative file paths of resources and map them to URL paths accordingly, so it works both on Windows and *nix the solution is:

```
<pathconvert dirsep="/" pathsep=";" property="css.files.list">
    <map from="${basedir}/" to="" /><!-- This is the trick. Remove slash to make path absolute. -->
    <fileset dir="." includes="${src.dir}/**/*.css" />
</pathconvert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either this one:

```
<pathconvert property="list-of-files">
  <globmapper from="*" to="src/*"/>
  <cutdirsmapper dirs="N"/>
  <fileset dir=${src-folder}/>
</pathconvert>
```

(here **N** - Number of directories to strip (must be a positive number))

or this:
after piece of your code treat list-of-files through the

```
<mapper type="flatten"/>
<flattenmapper/>
```

Hope this help =)

Comment: Unfortunately none of these works. I cannot use the first alternative because the nuber "N" is not constant in my builds. And the second alternative strips *all* folders and leave my with just a list of Java files. So I end up with: A.java,B.java,C.java which is not what I want.